# Custom model method in where query in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I need to use a model method named `calculate_reach` in my `where` query

```
@creators = User.joins(:identities, :roles).where("users.calculate_reach between ? and ?", '5000000', '5999999')
```

Basically, it's not recognizing `calculate_reach` bec. it's not an attribute of `users` table

How can I map results with custom method inside the WHERE clause. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@creators = User.joins(:identities, :roles).select do |u| 
  u.calculate_reach.between?(5000000, 5999999)
end
```

Something like this might do the trick. Assuming that `calculate_reach` returns a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot. God of queries. Thanks :) I think I need to review different query methods of RAILS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding Method to Model you can use scope to customize query you can refer link
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Thanks, how can I call a model method in this scope
`scope :fivemillion, where(calculate_reach: 2000)` the name of the method is `calculate_reach`

Comment: What is calculate_reach? If its method convert it into scope if this in not lengthy, You can pass parameter to scope as well, And also you can chain scope, directly call User.fivemillion(amount) not need of calculate_reach